# Can a Lucene index be stored in an RDBMS

Tags: lucene

If I don't have access to the file system, but do have access to a MySQL instance, can I store the lucene index in a mysql database.  I was able to find the [DbDirectory](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/store/db/DbDirectory.html) and thought that it might do the trick.  However, it looks like it works with a Berkeley DB rather than an RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont believe you can, it would defeat the purpose of Lucene. If your indexing does not take to long you could consider a RAMDirectory which I believe  stores it in memory.

Comment: The purpose of Lucene is searching. Why would storing the Lucene indexes in a database defeat that purpose?

Comment: The purpose of Lucene is to search fast and efficiently, effectively storing a database in a database is not efficient or logical.

Answer (score 3):

There are some contribution that stores lucene index in more simple datastores (from perspective of data model). For example, [BerkleyDB](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_4/api/contrib-bdb/org/apache/lucene/store/db/DbDirectory.html) and [Cassandra](http://blog.sematext.com/2010/02/09/lucandra-a-cassandra-based-lucene-backend/). So technically it is possible to write implementation of `Directory` which would store index in Jdbc. There  [is one](http://static.compassframework.org/docs/latest/jdbcdirectory.html) in Compass framework.